# How to share one view between two activities?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I have 2 activities in my application and I have a `RecyclerView` that should be in both of them.

Is there any way to share this `RecyclerView` with these activities or I have to define this `RecyclerView` in both of them separately?
(I don't want to use fragments in this app)

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably create a 'base' activity and share the layout between the two activities by extending it and use setContentView . You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011739/how-to-share-common-layout-between-activities-without-fragment)